# ¿ Google Play Games en Android Studio (Java)?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-games

Estoy realizando una App y no sé si hacerla en `Unity` o `Android Studio` pues necesito sí o sí incorporar `Google Play Games`. En `Unity` encuentro infinidad de ejemplos tanto en vídeo como por escrito pero en `Android Studio` no encuentro tanto ni tengo tanta experiencia.

¿Es posible realizar tablas de clasificación y demás configuraciones en Java? ¿ Cómo o qué guías puedo utilizar tan sencilla como la que explican en `Unity` como por ejemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ae8GeRmdH0 o https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity ??